# How much functionality is available on google maps when phone is out of signal?

Tags: android

I have an app I am working on, and it needs users to be able to select a location from an already specified list of locations when offline/out of signal. Some of the places are identically named but are in different areas. Is it possible to have the lat/long coordinates and have it displayed on a Google map window within the app when out of signal, or does Google maps not work offline in that matter? I've started to check the API, but I'm just thinking down the road a bit, so I haven't started to implement it yet. I was just wondering if any of you would already know the answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It does display cached places, and yes you can get lat/long

Comment: So I can cache the locations of the areas I want to use in my app, and will be able to pull them up within the app using the lat/long? Thank you so much. That will work great.

Comment: Yes, you can navigate to those places. In order to have them in cache. The lat/long feature always work